# KendoMobileListView - Would like to remove a leading black dot in each list item

Tags: listview, mobile, kendo-ui

I am new to KENDO mobile.
When I display my kendoMobileListView, for every item in the list I see a leading black dot.

can anyone tell me how should I hide this dot?

thanks

hagai

Answer (score 2):

This means that the Kendo Mobile CSS file is not properly loaded. Check if this is not the case.